# Unable to inject content script in cross origin iframe

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm creating chrome extension for Gmail. Anyhow, I have loaded https://example.com page in to extension in below manner.

1. Refer backgroundscript in manifest.json
2. In backgroundscript, injected content script and loaded an extension html file through "iframe"
3. Inside html file, I have loaded "iframe" for https://example.com

Till now content is loaded and it works fine.

Now I want to get thread id or some dom related ids from top frame (i.e Gmail main document)

I'm trying to inject another content script in cross origin iframe window (i.e example.com iframe window), but i'm not sure how to do it?

Manifest Json:

```
{
  "name": "gmailext12",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "description": "gmailext12",

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/16.png",
    "128": "images/128.png"
  },

  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["scripts/background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/16.png"
  },


   "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "identity",
        "https://*.google.com/*",
        "https://ssl.gstatic.com/",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/",
        "https://accounts.google.com/"
    ],


  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "iframe.html"
  ]
}
```

Background Js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

   chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "scripts/content.js"});

});
```

Content Script:

```
var element =  document.getElementById('gmail-123');

if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
   document.getElementById("gmail-123").remove();
}

var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;

if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    // Must be declared at web_accessible_resources in manifest.json

    iframe.id = 'gmail-123';

 iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html');

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);


}
```

Iframe Html:

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="gmail-111" src="https:example.com"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably need to add `allFrames: true` in the [second parameter of executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: If i do this, it is executed in all the frames. But i just want to do it for only cross origin frame.

Comment: Well then use chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames to enumerate the frames in that tab, get `frameId` of the target iframe, and use it in executeScript parameter.